# Build a volume meter for an HLS video managed with Hls.js

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, hls.js

I am using Hls.js to manage a video into my HTML page. I need to build a volume meter that inform the user about the audio level of the video. Since I need to keep the `video.muted = true`, I am wondering if the there is any way with Hls.js to extract the audio information from the stream and build a volume meter with those. The goal is give the users a feedback without have the volume of the video on.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with the Web Audio API.

Specifically, you'll want a couple nodes:

- [**MediaElementAudioSourceNode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode)
  You will use this to route the audio from your media element (i.e. the video element HLS.js is playing in) to the audio graph.
- [**AnalyserNode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode)
  This node analyzes the audio in chunks, giving you frequency data (via FFT) and time domain data.  The time domain data is simplified from the main stream.  You can run a min/max on it to get a value (generally -1.0 to +1.0).  You can use that value in your visualization.

You also need to connect the AnalyserNode to the AudioContext's `destinationNode` to output the audio in the end, since it will be re-routed from that video element.

Note that this solution isn't particular to HLS.  The same method works on any audio/video element, provided that the source data isn't tainted by cross-origin restrictions.  Given how HLS.js works, you won't have to worry about that, since the CORS problem is already solved or it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: If you use the Audio Context, you won't be able to access the informati on if the video is muted, since you will be analyzing the audio flow of the Window. lucataglia is asking if he can analyze the signal with the video MUTED.

Comment: @AleTheFe The audio output of the video is redirect into the audio context.  Unless you specifically connect that MediaElementAudioSourceNode to the destination, it will in effect be muted.

Comment: I tried what you say, but if I don't connect the node to the destinati on, the video does not play (i click play but the cursor won't move and the playback doesn't start). With the destination the rountrip works. Now since I don't want the final audio I thought about not connecting the node to the destination, but it doesn't work. Any idea of why?

Comment: @AleTheFe Without things connected, browsers will optimize the flow of the audio context and there will be essentially no "clock" keeping the audio moving.  If audio doesn't move, video won't play as it has to stay synchronized.  Use a gain node set to zero in between the source and the destination.