# noteOn is not a function

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, web-audio-api, hls.js

I have:

```js
          if ('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
            ctx = new webkitAudioContext()
          } else if ('AudioContext' in window) {
            ctx = new AudioContext()
          } else {
            console.log('Web Audio API is not available.')
          }
          audioHuman = document.getElementById("human")
          sourceHuman = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audioHuman)
          sourceHuman.connect(ctx.destination)
```

But then I get an error here:

```js
sourceHuman.noteOn(0)
```

> Uncaught TypeError: sourceHuman.noteOn is not a function

Why is `noteOn` method *not* defined?

### UPDATE

I'm using my HTML audio tag to stream by hls.js:

```html
    <audio id="human" preload="metadata" playsinline>
      <source src="media/human/playlist.m3u8">
      <source src="media/human.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="media/human.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="media/human.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio>
```

```js
function setupHls(media, mediaSrc) {
      if (Hls.isSupported()) { // Check if HLS.js is supported.
        var hls = new Hls()
        hls.loadSource(mediaSrc)
        hls.attachMedia(media)
      } else if (media.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) { // Check for native browser HLS support.
        media.src = mediaSrc
      } else {
        console.log("Your browser doesn't support HTTP Live Streaming.")
      }
    }

setupHls(document.getElementById("human"), 'media/human/playlist.m3u8')
```

I would like to get the audio streamed by HLS and process it with Web Audio API.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65786175/3405291), I guess I would have to use [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode). But I'm not quite sure how.

### UPDATE

By logging the output to console, I understand that the [MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaElementAudioSourceNode) is actually the output type of the [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) method.

Comment: `AudioContext.createMediaLementSource` returns an [`AudioNode` Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode), which has no `noteOn` method... Why you expected differently?

Comment: @DDomen Well, so how can one play the audio? I don't get it :)

Comment: @DDomen Alright, I think the playing is just through the HTML5 audio tag methods. Right?

Comment: `audioHuman.play()` should do in your case, but it depends what you want do achive by playing an audio source. Also check the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource#example) and an [implementation (MDN)](https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/media-source-buffer/) of it on how you should work with media element sources

Comment: @DDomen I tried to explain what I try to do by updating the post =)

Comment: I didn't actually worked so much with hls, but I guess is not so different from other audio apis. Maybe you are interested in using streams api with hls, so something like [`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource#example) could interesting for you. By the way any `AudioContext` related graph is controllable by the tag element `play/pause/stop` methods with this kind of api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @DDomen , what I didn't understand was the fact that HTML5 `<audio>` element `play/pause/stop` methods are still valid with `AudioContext`:

> Note: As a consequence of calling createMediaElementSource(), audio playback from the HTMLMediaElement will be re-routed into the processing graph of the AudioContext. So playing/pausing the media can still be done through the media element API and the player controls.

[image: Documentation]